Is my approach to this multivariable function word problem correct?
Word problem:
Lilian wants to construct a closed rectangular box with a square top and a volume of 96 cubic inches using two types of materials. The wooden material for the bottom and sides costs P5 per square inch while the glass material for the top costs twice as much per square inch as that for the wooden material. find the dimensions and cost of the least expensive box.
My answer:
https://imgur.com/a/nSuI6uY
